# How to use SharedPreferece for Android Typeface?

Tags: android

I created a sample application using Android **TextView with shared preferences**. In my application i have a sample textview which contains some text (Eg. "Android Font Text"), and also a had **set of fonts in my assets folder**. Here  my requirement is, **when i touch the textview, a sample dialog will popup in this pop up i shows the list of font's in assets folder**. When i select any one of the font it was changed successfully, it persist only in that particular activity. When i back to next activity the text view remains in **default style**. Here how can i achieve shared preferences for fonts. I can't pass the type face object through the editor. I used like this,

```
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"digit_fonts/AKEI____.TTF");
    font.isBold();
    mTextView.setTypeface(font);
    font_editor = font_pref.edit();
    font_editor.putString("font_style", font.toString());
    font_editor.commit();
```

Unfortunately it won't works, how can i acheive, if any one solve my problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Aerrow,make a common method for loading font and only store font name in sharedpreferences

Comment: I'm not clear in that, could you please post some example for this

Comment: I think what he's saying is, store the name of the font rather than font.toString() -- they aren't the same.  Also, create a separate method for loading the font, i.e., getFont(String file_name).

Comment: @lrAndroid : right i'm saying same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're trying to load a font from sharedpreferences whenever an activity is started?

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you need to do is
1) Save the file name of the font the user has chosen (i.e., "digit_fonts/AKEI_*_*.TTF")
2) Load the font using the file name saved in shared preferences, for example:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),font_pref.getString("font_style", default_font_filename));
```

Then apply the font as you normally would.

EDIT:

To load:

```
font_style = font_pref.getString("font_style", null);
if (font_style!=null){
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),font_style);
    font.isBold();
    mTextView.setTypeface(font);
}
```

To save:

```
font_editor = font_pref.edit();
font_editor.putString("font_style", font_style);
font_editor.commit();
```

As you can see, font_style is actually the file location of your font (the way I've coded it above).  When the user chooses a font, you alter font_style then save it to preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, sorry for asking instead of "default_font_filename", which variable i use?

Comment: That would be something like "digit_fonts/AKEI__.TTF", or wherever your 'default' font is stored.  Another option would be to get the String from sharedpreferences seperately (leaving the second parameter, or default value, all null).  The you can have your program only set the font if the above variable is not equal to null.

Comment: Could you please alter and post the correct code to set the preference and get the preferences,

Comment: See EDIT.  If you have any other questions, feel free to send me an email.

Comment: Unfortunately, Typeface.createFromAsset creates memory leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901930/memory-leaks-with-custom-font-for-set-custom-font. So is there a way to save the typeface after all, instead of only the filename?