# Memory leaks with custom font for set custom font

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

The following code for setting custom fonts slows down my whole app. how do i modify it to avoid memory leaks and increase the speed and manage memory well?

```
public class FontTextView extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "FontTextView";

    public FontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTextView);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.FontTextView_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"fonts/"+ asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You should cache the TypeFace, otherwise [you might risk memory leaks on older handsets](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904). Caching will increase speed as well since it's not super fast to read from assets all the time.

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if(tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

I gave a [full example on how to load custom fonts and style textviews as an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648457/1266551). You seem to be doing most of it right, but you should cache the font as recommended above.

Comment: how do i call fontcache i nmy code for setcustomfont? i cant get it right everytime i try

Comment: Replace tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"fonts/"+ asset); with tf = FontCache.get("fonts/" + asset, ctx);

Comment: Is there a reason to use `Hashtable`? If not, `ArrayMap` might be a better type due lower memory consumption and iteration speed.

Comment: I didn't actually put much thought into the choice of data structure. ArrayMap might work equally well or better!

Comment: I am not sure if this was always the case, but the `createFromAsset()` method already uses a dynamic [`LruCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) to store each `Typeface`. This method is wasting resources by creating a second cache.

Comment: Using `Calligraphy` library for Font is much better than this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I feel using the Font cache is not needed.Can we do this way?

A minor change to the above code, Correct me if i am wrong.

```
public class FontTextView extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "FontTextView";
    private static Typeface mTypeface;

    public FontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),   GlobalConstants.SECONDARY_TTF);
        }
        setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

    }
```

Comment: If you are going to have only one Font, this solution would work. Other solutions are better for multiple font cases.

Comment: Yes, But it is not recommended having more fonts for single android application i think.?

Comment: I never heard anything like that. If you have a resource, I would like to read