# How can i save font typeface in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save font typeface in SharedPreferences. But i unable to achieve it, please help me.Thanks
     Here is my code.

to read..

```
SharedPreferences fontSP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFSFONT", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


m_txTitle.setTypeface(fontSP.getString("fontValue", SettingsABC.getTypeface(fontStyle));
```

to save..

```
fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "caligula.ttf");
                    SharedPreferences fontSP = getSharedPreferences("PREFSFONT", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor bgEditor = fontSP.edit();
                    bgEditor.putString("fontValue", fontStyle.toString());
                    bgEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the Font object's `toString()` into the preferences, and then trying to use that to restore the value, which I'm 99.9% sure will not work. `toString()` is not a serialization mechanism.

Instead, you should write the filename and restore using that that.

```
bgEditor.putString("fontValue", "caligula.ttf"); //Use the filename here
```

Then to restore:

```
fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontSP.getString("fontValue", SettingsABC.getTypeface(fontStyle));
m_txTitle.setTypeface(fontStyle);
```

Or something close to that.

Comment: that to string() i added since bgEditor.putString(string,string). Also the following statement is wrong.                                                   fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontSP.getString("fontValue", SettingsABC.getTypeface(fontStyle));

Comment: But you don't want to read a typeface, you want to read from the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, Typeface.createFromAsset creates memory leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901930/memory-leaks-with-custom-font-for-set-custom-font. So is there a way to save the typeface after all, instead of only the filename?